# Stream - Length of Content

Tags: c#

Is there no way to get the length of the content currently held by the stream?

I thought Length would give me what I am looking for, but it did not match up in my test.

```
public class Solution {

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var raw = new byte[] { 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5 };
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(3)) {
            long size = stream.Length;              // Actual 0, expected 0
            long capacity = stream.Capacity;        // Actual 3, expected 3
            long position = stream.Position;        // Actual 0, expected 0

            stream.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
            size = stream.Length;                   // Actual 6, expected 6
            capacity = stream.Capacity;             // Actual 256, expected big enough to hold content
            position = stream.Position;             // Actual 6, expected 6

            var buffer = new byte[1];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1);
            size = stream.Length;                   // Actual 6, expected 5
            capacity = stream.Capacity;             // Actual 256, expected same as before
            position = stream.Position;             // Actual 6, expected 5

            stream.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
            size = stream.Length;                   // Actual 12, expected 11
            capacity = stream.Capacity;             // Actual 256, expected same as before
            position = stream.Position;             // Actual 12, expected 11

            stream.Seek(0, 0);
            size = stream.Length;                   // Actual 12, expected 11
            position = stream.Position;             // Actual 0, expected 0
        }
    }
}
```

I'd expect the read to decrease the size by 1. It apparently, does not. This raises the question then, if the byte is retained in memory and the length is reported including read bytes, when then is it removed from memory? (We can't accumulate forever!) and how do we get the Length of the current content? (total bytes written - total bytes read)?

Edit:
I've figured out that position remains at the end of the stream upon the first write, if you do not seek backwards. Position is shared for read and writes. However, the other questions still remain.

Comment: why do you think reading a byte should remove it from the stream?

Comment: @SelmanGenç Because that's the way I am used to streams working in other languages. If it is not removed when you read it, then when is it removed? We can't accumulate forever, can we? Perhaps a tutorial on C# streams in in order here. They seem to work a bit differently than what I am used to.

Comment: "the way I am used to streams working in other languages" That's your first problem. You can't assume that things work the same way in every language.

Comment: @KennethK Hence, why I am here, asking these questions after running tests to see if they matched my expectations

Comment: Sounds like the thing you really want to work with is .Position.

Comment: If you want to know what operations remove data from the stream then look at the documentation for the type.  It covers what operations remove data from the underlying stream.

Comment: @Clay No, position does not appear to be the same thing as the length of the current unread content.

Comment: Nope - my bad. But the behavior you're looking for won't be found on a memory stream. It's way simpler a construct than that. Check out the docs for Stream. Some derivations *may* act in the way you're expecting. If I remember correctly, the streams in a named pipe can behave the way you're expecting.

Comment: Edited code example to include size and position sampling.

Comment: maybe you want channels https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/channels

Answer (score 0):

In c#,

> Stream is the abstract base class of all streams. A stream is an abstraction of a sequence of bytes, such as a file, an input/output device, an inter-process communication pipe, or a TCP/IP socket. The Stream class and its derived classes provide a generic view of these different types of input and output, and isolate the programmer from the specific details of the operating system and the underlying devices. [read MS source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=netframework-4.7.2)

You should notice that it is not an abstraction of a `Stack` or a `Queue`. This might well be the concept actually used during implementation, but that is moot. What is important however is that

> Streams involve three fundamental operations:
>
> - You can read from streams. Reading is the transfer of data from a stream into a data structure, such as an array of bytes.
> - You can write to streams. Writing is the transfer of data from a data structure into a stream.
> - Streams can support seeking. Seeking refers to querying and modifying the current position within a stream. Seek capability depends on the kind of backing store a stream has. For example, network streams have no unified concept of a current position, and therefore typically do not support seeking.

What you are actually doing when reading from a stream is

> writing the specified number of items from `.Position` in the stream into a buffer starting at the given location in the buffer

This means that the contents of the `Stream` remain within the `Stream` after they have been read. It is only a call to `Flush` that clears buffered data from the `Stream` [see MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.flush?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Getting `Position` gives the position within the stream where the next read/write operation would begin from if calling `stream.Write( … )` or `stream.Read( … )`. Setting `Position` sets the position within the stream where the next read or write operation will begin from when called.

```
     const int numberOfBytesToRead = 2;
     const int streamStart = 0;
     using (var stream = new MemoryStream(3))
     {
        Debug.Assert(stream.Length == 0);
        Debug.Assert(stream.Capacity == 3);
        Debug.Assert(stream.Position == 0);
        stream.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);

        Debug.Assert(stream.Length == raw.Length);
        Debug.Assert(stream.Position == 6);

        stream.Position = streamStart;
        Debug.Assert(stream.Position == 0);
        var buffer = new byte[numberOfBytesToRead];
        var bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        Debug.Assert(bytesRead == numberOfBytesToRead);
        Debug.Assert(stream.Length == raw.Length);
        Debug.Assert(stream.Position == numberOfBytesToRead);

        stream.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
        Debug.Assert(stream.Length == raw.Length+numberOfBytesToRead);
        Debug.Assert(stream.Position == raw.Length + numberOfBytesToRead);
        stream.Position = raw.Length;

        buffer = new byte[numberOfBytesToRead];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        var builder = new StringBuilder("|");
        foreach (var item in buffer)
           builder.Append($"{item}|");

        Debug.Assert(builder.ToString().Equals("|5|6|"));

        builder = new StringBuilder("|");
        buffer = new byte[numberOfBytesToRead+raw.Length];
        stream.Position = streamStart;
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        foreach (var item in buffer)
           builder.Append($"{item}|");

        Debug.Assert(builder.ToString().Equals("|1|2|1|2|3|4|5|6|"));
     }
```

Comment: Sorry - but there are read-only streams and write only streams and *lots* of streams definitely don't support seeking. Of course, you're suppose to indicate whether it's legal to read, write, or seek by overrriding .CanRead, .CanWrite and .CanSeek. Even .Position isn't a guarantee.

Comment: So, OP is probably talking about the [Position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.position) property

Comment: `Flush` is there to write out data that was written to the stream, but not to the underlying data source.  It's won't remove memory from a MemoryStream that has been read.

Comment: There is nothing to be sorry about @Clay, as you can see in my answer, _Streams **can support** seeking_ which implies that they do not all. Also, Servy, from the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.flush?view=netframework-4.7.2) … Override Flush on streams that implement a buffer. Use this method to move any information from an underlying buffer to its destination, clear the buffer, or both, which means that the Stream will still remain the size it grew to, but will then contain no buffered data.

Comment: @BillRichards And yet you've made statements about all streams that only apply to certain streams.

Comment: @BillRichards Yes, and what about that description gives you the impression that it results in deleting content from a MemoryStream that has been read from, as you claim it will?

Comment: @Servy, … I'm not sure what your point is. I've clearly stated that _reading from a Stream does not remove the data_ you appear to be arguing with me saying `it doesn't remove the data though`

Comment: No, I'm saying that you're claiming that `Flush` will remove data from the stream, and it will not.  In the case of a MemoryStream, as is being used here, it will do literally nothing at all, as the stream doesn't have any buffers to flush in the first place.

Comment: Sorry pal, but I'm making no such claim. I have merely repeated the text from the MS documentation. I have said that  It is **only** a call to Flush that clears buffered data from the Stream. I have not said  **every** call to Flush that clears buffered data from the Stream.

Comment: `Flush` will do literally nothing in the case of a MemoryStream.  There is never anything to flush, ever.  It will *never* affect the underlying data of a MemoryStream, in any way.

Comment: Can you guys take your argument into a private chat? It's just becoming clutter at this point.

Comment: @Rubens No, position does not appear to be the same thing as the length of the current unread content.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want bytes remaining, which you can get with simple math.

```
var bytesRemaining = stream.Length - stream.Position;
```

Comment: This would be 0 after the first write, which is not correct.